# Unable to import Spring Security @Secured Annotation into Grails 3

Tags: spring, grails, spring-security, spring-annotations

I am currently following the Spring Security 3.0.0.M1 plugin tutorial for Grails [here](https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/guide/tutorials.html) and I appear to be stuck on Step 8. Using the statement `import grails.plugin.springsecurity.annotation.Secured` does not work because Grails cannot resolve the package name. I know that Spring Security for Grails 3 is in its infancy, but has anyone been able to get past this step yet? For reference, here is my SecureController class (with a another import that also does not work):

```
package ldaptest.controllers

import grails.plugin.springsecurity.annotation.Secured;
import org.springframework.security.access.annotation.Secured;

@Secured('ROLE_ADMIN')
class SecureController {

    def index() {
        render 'Secure access only'
    }
}
```

Comment: Currently you have 2 imports, that isn't going to work either way.

Comment: I know that. I kept both in case it motivates someone to help find the answer.

Comment: I've got the same problem. Intellij 15 with Grails 3.0.9 and Gradle. My suspicion is, that my plugins are not download probably. And why SpringsSecurity is the first plugin which is called, it seems to fail only for SpringSecurity? When I check the dependencies with gradle everything seems alright.

Answer (score 2):

I may found a solution:

1. Create a "lib" folder e.g. inside your "grails-app" directory.
2. Download the SpringSecurityCore JAR from [here](https://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/plugins/spring-security-core/3.0.0.M1/) and move it into the lib directory
3. Add gradle dependency:

   compile files('lib/spring-security-core-3.0.0.M1.jar')

Hope this helps.
Greetings

Comment: Hi Mexx. Thanks for the suggestion, but it appears that the import works now ever since the plugin was migrated to Grails 3 on Bintray

Answer (score 0):

I had:3,1,1 the save problem with my application. I solved it by adding as a library to my project. However I had to change import package to make it work.

```
import org.springframework.security.access.annotation.Secured
```

I am using IntelliJ IDEA, I just has to search the maven repo for the spring-security-core:3.1.1. 
In IntelliJ you do : File > Project Structure > Libraries > Add > From Maven Repository. Then do the search according to the version of "spring-security-core" you want to use.